# Where do I make mistake in comparing two csv files in powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to compare two csv files and create third csv file with differencies.

First csv file is this:

```
Name     PowerState
----     ----------
vm1      VM deallocated
vm2      VM deallocated
vm3      No data
vm4      No data
vm5      VM deallocated
```

Second csv:

```
Name     PowerState
----     ----------
vm1      VM deallocated
vm2      VM running
vm3      VM running
vm4      VM deallocated
vm5      VM deallocated
```

I want to compare with powershell so this is my code:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\csv1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\csv2.csv

 $output = @()
   forEach ($Row in $csv1) {    
     $powerstate = "ShutdownScriptState: " + $Row.PowerState + " | Now: " + $result.PowerState
     $output += New-object PSObject -property @{
       Name = $Row.Name
       PowerState = $powerstate
     }
   }

   $result = $csv2 | where {$_.csv2 -ne $name.PowerState}


 $output | select-object Name, PowerState | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\final.csv -NoTypeInformation -delimiter ","
```

But on output final.csv is not complete:

```
Name            PowerState
----            ----------
adfs            ShutdownScriptState: VM deallocated | Now: 
adfs40          ShutdownScriptState: VM deallocated | Now: 
ardal           ShutdownScriptState: No data | Now: 
backupDPM       ShutdownScriptState: No data | Now: 
BizTalk2016     ShutdownScriptState: VM deallocated | Now:
```

Missing Now: ($result.PowerState)

I can´t figure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `Compare-Object` to do the comparison and afterwards group on Name to get the differences side by side.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51428482.ps1
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\csv1.csv'
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\csv2.csv'

$Result = Compare-Object $csv1 $csv2 -Property Name,PowerState |
  Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object{
      [PSCustomObject]@{
          Name  = $_.Name
          Powerstate_1st = ($_.Group | Where SideIndicator -eq "<=").Powerstate
          Powerstate_Now = ($_.Group | Where SideIndicator -eq "=>").Powerstate
      }
  }
$Result
$Result | Export-Csv '.\final.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample Output

```
Name Powerstate_1st Powerstate_Now
---- -------------- --------------
vm2  VM deallocated VM running
vm3  No data        VM running
vm4  No data        VM deallocated
```

To have **exactly** your desired output change above `[PSCustomObject]` to

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Name  = $_.Name
    Powerstate = ("ShutdownScriptState: {0} | {1}" -f `
       ($_.Group | Where SideIndicator -eq "<=").Powerstate,
       ($_.Group | Where SideIndicator -eq "=>").Powerstate)
}
```

---

```
Name Powerstate
---- ----------
vm2  ShutdownScriptState: VM deallocated | VM running
vm3  ShutdownScriptState: No data | VM running
vm4  ShutdownScriptState: No data | VM deallocated
```

Comment: it´s showing both states but not merging it into one row. It create 5 rows vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4 vm5 with states of first csv and under that rows it create vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4 vm5 with states of second csv. So it´s only two csv files in one csv file.

Comment: The pure `Compare-Object` does it that way, but the above script  and output are from your sample data and not a fake, so if you get that output with the script something went wrong on copy/paste.

Comment: Okey. After hour I know where is problem. When I open my csv file thrue Lister it´s have "" everywhere and new file that I created doesn´t have "" so it´s working. Thank you for help your code is working :)

Answer (score 0):

You tried to access the `$Result` variable before you set it, and from within a different scope.

Move

```
$result = $csv2 | where {$_.csv2 -ne $name.PowerState}
```

Inside your ForEach loop just before

```
$powerstate = "ShutdownScriptState: " + $Row.PowerState + " | Now: " + $result.PowerState
```

You also need to change that line to:

```
$result = $csv2 | where {$_.Name -eq $Row.Name}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were accessing variables out of order and not comparing properly.  This snippet should resolve your problem concisely:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\csv1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\csv2.csv

$output = foreach ($row in $csv1) {
    $compare = $csv2 | Where-Object Name -eq $row.Name
    if ($row.PowerState -ne $compare.PowerState) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name       = $row.Name
            PowerState = "ShutdownScriptState: $($row.PowerState) | Now: $($compare.PowerState)"
        }
    }
}

$output | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\final.csv -NoTypeInformation
```